# What is the correct way to load a scene in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My menu scene doesn't work when coming from gameplay scene.

I have two scenes:

**MainMenuScene** with a timeline and this script:

```
public void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("MainMenuScene.Start");

    var timelineMain = GameObject.Find("timelineMain").GetComponent<PlayableDirector>();
    timelineMain.Play();
}

public void playGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("GameplayScene", LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

**GameplayScene** with pause HUD and quit to main menu button that runs:

```
public void playGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("GameplayScene", LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

On first open the MainMenuScene is working good, but after enter game and click Quit button the scene is loaded but nothing works.

What happens:

- The scene appears on screen
- I can see `Start()` message from `Debug.Log()`
- The timeline animation does not start
- Menu buttons not works anymore to start game
- No errors on console
- Objects `DontDestroyOnLoad` from game scene still appears on Hierarchy panel

Am I doing something wrong? What is the correct way to completely reset/reload a scene?

Comment: correct, dont destroy objects and changed when the scene is reloaded, so any scene specific items they reference are lost and need refinding

Comment: Start only occurs once, have you tried Awake?

Comment: @Pow Tried Start and Awake and both shows Debug.Log() message but the timeline doesn't start.

Comment: so, does  the timerlineMain exist? does that component still exist on it? do you get any errors?

Comment: yes timeline exists normally... I have created a fresh scene to test without my gameplayscene and it worked... main menu going and returning from test scene... so it's a problem related with my gameplay scene... when it returns from that, I few objects from gameplay are still on DestroyOnLoad, like Rewired Input manager, Dialogue Manager (from UNity Dialogue System) and a singleton of my GameManager class.. is there any way to get rid of those things?

Comment: but where does timeline exist, if its in the scene you need to refind it each scene change, if its in the dont destroy section it should stay..

Comment: @BugFinder the problem I see is that when come from an fresh scene that works... but when comes from my gameplay scene, it doesn't work... and the only thing I see different is DontDesroyOnLoad... I dont think is some related to the timeline

Comment: are you sure you're not trying to access the timeline before its loaded? Also, I would reccomend trying gamedev stack exchange for game dev questions.

Answer (score 0):

When You Start a scene all scene references are assigned ids .
Variables in menu are references to the game objects.
when you come back from gameplay scene these game objects are assigned new ids.
so you are referencing wrong ids which are not there anymore.
Solution is to either persist all related objects. i.e.
object having references and referenced objects.
or assign new values when you came back from another scene